# Cannot find the daemon.json file in windows 10 after docker-desktop installation

Tags: docker, windows-10, daemon, docker-for-windows

I installed the docker-desktop in windows 10 using the installer. Now i want to see the configuration file daemon.json. The official documentation says that

> The default location of the configuration file on Windows is %programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json

But i cannot find a folder %programdata%\docker.Instead, the folder C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop exists. But that doesn't have a daemon.json file in it.

Can someone help me to find why this is so and where can i find daemon.json?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

On my system the file is at `%userprofile%\.docker\daemon.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Actually I have the file there itself. But after editing this file, docker always fails to start. Then docker started only after resetting docker to factory defaults (Because it reverts the changes i made to the daemon.json file).

Comment: In the Docker setting in the Deamon category you can switch to Advanced and also edit the deamon.json file. Maybe edit it there to be sure to edit the correct one.

Comment: Actually the problem is, i want to change the settings of docker desktop ( such as exposing the daemon to 2375 tcp port) without using GUI. That's why i thought to edit the daemon.json file. This is for the purpose of automation.

Comment: @JohannesBuchholz it still fails to restart after modifying the values directly from the Docker console. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Running Docker Desktop elevated to admin solved for me @AnjanaAK

Answer (score 3):

Right click Docker icon in taskbar > Click Settings > Click Docker Engine

You can update that, and it should work. I'm on Docker Engine v19.03.8.

Answer (score 1):

The path `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`, as described in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon), is correct, or also correct.

I think the file is not created until you change it on GUI. Once you change it on GUI,the file will be were is supposed with the exact content you apply.

Comment: This seems to only apply to windows containers, or rather the version of docker hosting them